# How to draw a tree in MATLAB such that its edges are at right angles?

Tags: matlab, graph, graphics, tree, visualization

With `treeplot`, I get this:

```
nodes = [0 1 2 2 4 4 4 1 8 8 10 10];
treeplot(nodes)
```

[image]

How can I draw a tree like a dendrogram (with straight edges/branches)? Like this figure below, which I drew the following with Python's `plotly`, not of the same tree though, but its just to demonstrate the kind of visualization I want:

[image]

When I check the doc for `treeplot`, it says:

```
treeplot(P,nodeSpec,edgeSpec) allows optional parameters nodeSpec
and edgeSpec to set the node or edge color, marker, and linestyle.
Use '' to omit one or both.
```

But it does not state any option for making a straight-edged tree instead of the default "angular" one.

Comment: Your second picture glitched out

Comment: @Durkee Means? I didn't get it.

Comment: If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you could perhaps use [`dendrogram`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dendrogram.html) (with some modifications to your data).

Comment: @gnovice I know; that is what I drew in the second picture with Python. But I do not want a dendrogram here, which is by definition a binary tree. I want to draw any tree in the "style" of `dendrogram` with straight lines for edges.

Comment: It's fixed now but originally the python picture wasn't showing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a little bit of a kluge to do, since the line handles aren't returned by [`treeplot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/treeplot.html), and the line objects aren't [tagged](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html#property_d0e589821) to easily find them. But if it's the only thing you've plotted in the current axes then the following should find the right line objects and modify them accordingly:

```
treeplot(nodes);                              % Plot tree
hLines = get(gca, 'Children');                % Get handles to children of axes
x = reshape(get(hLines(1), 'XData'), 3, []);  % Get and reshape x data
y = reshape(get(hLines(1), 'YData'), 3, []);  % Get and reshape y data
x = x([1 1 2 3], :);                          % Replicate first row of x
y = y([1 2 2 3], :);                          % Replicate second row of y
set(hLines(1), 'XData', x(:).', 'YData', y(:).');  % Reshape and update data
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I wanted.